# Character movement, changing players animation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I made a script for moving the character and setting animation. When player wants to go right animation is set into the one with character facing the right side and walking. Everything is working perfectly until you want to move in two directions at once, let's say up and left. Character goes by resultant of that two forces, but animation is going crazy. I made quickfix for this, by not allowing to play left, right when any other animation is playing.
I was thinking about something like this:
When you are going right, u are facing the right side. Still going, then you press up button you are going into north-east side, but you are still facing right.
So you are about to face that side you wanted to go first, in this example right.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class player_movement : MonoBehaviour {
    //przyciski do poruszania się
    private KeyCode right_key = KeyCode.D;
    private KeyCode left_key = KeyCode.A;
    private KeyCode up_key = KeyCode.W;
    private KeyCode down_key = KeyCode.S;

    //poruszanie się gracza right == true => porusza się w prawo, left == true => porusza się w lewo; itp..
    private bool right;
    private bool left;
    private bool up;
    private bool down;

    player_statistics player; //zmienna przechowująca klasę? odnośnik do klasy? (yy nie wiem jak to nazwać)

    void Start ()
    {
        //przypisanie klasy do zmiennej, funkcji, klasy, no właśnie
        player = GameObject.FindWithTag("Player").GetComponent<player_statistics>();
    }

    void Update ()
    {
        movement_xy(); //wowołanie fukncji odp za wykrycie wciśnięcia klawiszy odp za poruszanie się
        movement_animation();
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (right || left || up || down) //wywołanie funkcji odp poruszanie się
        {
            movement_force();
        }
    }



    void movement_xy()
    {


        //ustawienie zmiennej odpowiedzialnej za ruch w prawo
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(right_key))
        {
            right = true;
        }
        if (Input.GetKeyUp(right_key))
        {
            right = false;
            GetComponent<Animator>().Play("idle_right", 0);
        }

        //ustawienie zmiennej odpowiedzialnej za ruch w lewo
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(left_key))
        {
            left = true;
        }
        if (Input.GetKeyUp(left_key))
        {
            left = false;
        }

        //ustawienie zmiennej odpowiedzialnej za ruch w górę
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(up_key))
        {
            up = true;
        }
        if (Input.GetKeyUp(up_key))
        {
            up = false;
            GetComponent<Animator>().Play("idle_up", 0);
        }

        //ustawienie zmiennej odpowiedzialnej za ruch w dół 
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(down_key))
        {
            down = true;
        }
        if (Input.GetKeyUp(down_key))
        {
            down = false;
            GetComponent<Animator>().Play("idle_down", 0);
        }
    }

    void movement_force()
    {
        // przykładanie do postaci danej sił fizycznej na osi X i Y
        if (left && player.player_gameobject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.x > -5)
        {
            player.player_rigidbody.AddForce(new Vector2(-player.movement_speed, 0), ForceMode2D.Impulse);
        }
        if (right && player.player_gameobject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.x < 5)
        {
            player.player_rigidbody.AddForce(new Vector2(player.movement_speed, 0), ForceMode2D.Impulse);
        }
        if (up && player.player_gameobject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.y < 5)
        {
            player.player_rigidbody.AddForce(new Vector2(0, player.movement_speed), ForceMode2D.Impulse);
        }
        if (down && player.player_gameobject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.y > -5)
        {
            player.player_rigidbody.AddForce(new Vector2(0, -player.movement_speed), ForceMode2D.Impulse);
        }
    }




    void movement_animation()
    {
        if(right && !up && !down) //quick fix, not like this helped but character animation isnt in crazy angry kid state
        {
            GetComponent<Animator>().Play("go_right", 0);
        }
        if (left && !up && !down)
        {
            GetComponent<Animator>().Play("go_left", 0);
        }
        if (up)
        {
            GetComponent<Animator>().Play("go_up", 0);
        }
        if (down)
        {
            GetComponent<Animator>().Play("go_down", 0);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok i got this.

```
    void movement_animation()
{
    if(right && !left && !up && !down)
    {
        GetComponent<Animator>().Play("go_right", 0);
    }
    if (left && !right && !up && !down)
    {
        GetComponent<Animator>().Play("go_left", 0);
    }
    if (up && !down && !left && !right)
    {
        GetComponent<Animator>().Play("go_up", 0);
    }
    if (down && !up && !left && !right)
    {
        GetComponent<Animator>().Play("go_down", 0);
    }
}
```

and

```
void movement_animation()
{
    if(right && !left && !up && !down) //quick fix, not like this helped but character animation isnt in crazy angry kid state
    {
        GetComponent<Animator>().Play("go_right", 0);
    }
    if (left && !right && !up && !down)
    {
        GetComponent<Animator>().Play("go_left", 0);
    }
    if (up && !down && !left && !right)
    {
        GetComponent<Animator>().Play("go_up", 0);
    }
    if (down && !up && !left && !right)
    {
        GetComponent<Animator>().Play("go_down", 0);
    }
}
```

No more bugging animations.

Comment: You could simplify that by using else if and removing the subsequently tested value in its previous if statement.